# Блокировка доступа к меню браузера и его адресной строке

Tags: javascript, html, css, окно, блокировки

```
if (confirm('Хотите открыть предыдущую лабораторную работу?')) {
   window.open("lab13.html", '_blank',width=400,height=400,left=200,top=100,status=0,location=0,menubar=0)
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой , должна отсутствовать строка статуса, заблокирован доступ к меню браузера и его адресной строке, почему-то , когда открывается новый файл , последние три события не работают , с чем это связано ?

Comment: С безопасностью.

Comment: как его отключить ?

Comment: Написать свой браузер?

Comment: Запустить браузер в режиме киоска

Comment: Какие 3 событие ?